# Generic uniform values

Tags: opengl

Is there way to pass data addressed by native pointer as uniform?
Something like void setUniform(GLuint location,int size, void* data). Without using uniform blocks or changing shader code.

Comment: What would you do with it, without any type information?

Comment: You can set arbitrary data in an UBO. You still need a way to tell the shader what's inside, though.